# Bootstrap class formatting breaking my Flask WTForms

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, flask-wtforms

I have this WTForms template which produces a simple form with text fields, radio buttons and a submit button.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method=post>

        <h3>Part I,</h3><h4>G1</h4><div class="well span6">

        {{ form.node_1.label }}    
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            {% for subfield in form.freq_1 %}<tr><td>{{ subfield }}</td><td>{{ subfield.label }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}
        </form></div><h4>G2</h4><div class="well span6">

        {{ form.node_2.label }}
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            {% for subfield in form.freq_2 %}<tr><td>{{ subfield }}</td><td>{{ subfield.label }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}
        </form></div>

        <h3>Part II</h3>

        <div class="well span6">
            {{ form.extra1.label }} {{ form.extra1}}
            {{ form.extra1Email.label }} {{ form.extra1Email }}
            {{ form.extra1Group.label }} {{ form.extra1Group }}
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                {% for subfield in form.extra1Freq %}<tr><td>{{ subfield }}</td><td>{{ subfield.label }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}            
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="well span6">    
            {{ form.extra2.label }} {{ form.extra2}}
            {{ form.extra2Email.label }} {{ form.extra2Email }}
            {{ form.extra2Group.label }} {{ form.extra2Group }}
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                {% for subfield in form.extra2Freq %}<tr><td>{{ subfield }}</td><td>{{ subfield.label }}</td></tr>{% endfor %}
            </form>
        </div>

        {{ form.submit }}

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here's the html Flask produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">Title</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/network">Network</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">    
        <form action="/" method=post>
            <h3>Part I,</h3>
            <h4>G1</h4>
            <div class="well span6">
                <label for="node_1">First name 1 Last name 1</label>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input checked id="freq_1-0" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-0">1</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_1-1" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-1">2</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_1-2" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-2">3</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_1-3" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="30">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-3">4</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_1-4" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="183">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-4">5</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_1-5" name="freq_1" type="radio" value="365">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_1-5">6</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h4>G2</h4>
            <div class="well span6">
                <label for="node_2">First name 2 Last name 1</label>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input checked id="freq_2-0" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-0">1</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_2-1" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-1">2</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_2-2" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-2">3</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_2-3" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="30">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-3">4</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_2-4" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="183">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-4">5</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="freq_2-5" name="freq_2" type="radio" value="365">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="freq_2-5">6</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h3>Part II</h3>
            <div class="well span6">
                <label for="extra1">First and Last name:</label>
                <input id="extra1" name="extra1" type="text" value="">
                <label for="extra1Email">Email:</label>
                <input id="extra1Email" name="extra1Email" type="text" value="">
                <label for="extra1Group">Company or Group:</label>
                <input id="extra1Group" name="extra1Group" type="text" value="">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra1Freq-0" name="extra1Freq" type="radio" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra1Freq-0">1</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra1Freq-1" name="extra1Freq" type="radio" value="7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra1Freq-1">2</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra1Freq-2" name="extra1Freq" type="radio" value="30">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra1Freq-2">3</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra1Freq-3" name="extra1Freq" type="radio" value="183">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra1Freq-3">4</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra1Freq-4" name="extra1Freq" type="radio" value="365">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra1Freq-4">5</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="well span6">
                <label for="extra2">First and Last name:</label>
                <input id="extra2" name="extra2" type="text" value="">
                <label for="extra2Email">Email:</label>
                <input id="extra2Email" name="extra2Email" type="text" value="">
                <label for="extra2Group">Company or Group:</label>
                <input id="extra2Group" name="extra2Group" type="text" value="">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra2Freq-0" name="extra2Freq" type="radio" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra2Freq-0">1</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra2Freq-1" name="extra2Freq" type="radio" value="7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra2Freq-1">2</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra2Freq-2" name="extra2Freq" type="radio" value="30">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra2Freq-2">3</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra2Freq-3" name="extra2Freq" type="radio" value="183">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra2Freq-3">4</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="extra2Freq-4" name="extra2Freq" type="radio" value="365">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="extra2Freq-4">5</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send your form">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use Bootstrap 3 to format the lists of buttons by attributing a class to parts of the form:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
```

For some reasons, using these classes "breaks" my form, in that clicking the "submit" button doesn't register or lead anywhere. When I remove the above line (and their relative "") from the form, I am then able to submit.

What is wrong with my use of these Bootstrap classes? What is the proper way to use them?

Comment: are checking for the submit in your view functions? and how do you equip the base.html with bootstrap? showing that could be critical to solving your problem. suggesting an edit also.

Comment: you have a form in a form? why are you doing that? I think you probably need something more like this: <div class="form-group"> instead of <form class="form-inline" role="form">. As far as I know only the outer block should be the form.

Comment: Thanks so much @wgwz! I'll try your idea about getting rid of forms within form... I do check for submit in the view function, but what do you mean by how I equip the base.html with bootstrap? I put <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}"> in the head part of the html, but I'm guessing you mean something else?

Comment: Using <div class="form-inline"> instead of <form class="form-inline" role="form"> worked! the newbie I am learnt something valuable thanks to you... Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Thank very much indeed...